# How to display ant design flow chart? Can you help me?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I'm working with ant design chart, specifically is flow chart of it. I use the basic code on this: "https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/flowchart/basic#basic". But I have a problem is I can not render the flow chart as the example. Do you know how to display it? Can you help me with this. Thank you very much!

This is the code sandbox link for this, but on code sandbox it is not display too.
https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-forest-uz2xrf

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/what-is-a-flowchart-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not displaying because of missing dependencies. Add **`@ant-design/icons`** and **`antd`** as an dependency after that it will display.

We will also need to import the necessary css file also, without it the flowchart widgets will be unresponsive and disproportionate. You can add css file by adding this line.
**`import '@ant-design/flowchart/dist/index.css';`**

As of now, It does not work with **`React.StrictMode`**. So remove it.

Comment: yes I did, but it still not work :(((

Comment: Check your codesandbox.io link which you have provided in question. I have checked by adding dependencies there. It is working. @JtaDD

Comment: can you share for me again, I can not see the change, pls. Thank you

Comment: @JtaDD Try this link [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-forest-uz2xrf)

Comment: yes it displayed and i known it, but it's not like the base on their home page. LMAO

Comment: https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/flowchart/basic#basic
you can see in this link

Comment: Yes. It was not like their homepage because of CSS. LMAO. Import the CSS and it will work. I have updated the answer and it is working exactly like their homepage now. You can check on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-haze-t577e4?file=/index.js)

Comment: but when I use it in an IDE, it throw some error like this: "Failed to parse source map from '/home/datdt/Desktop/examples/antv/node_modules/inversify/src/utils/serialization.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/datdt/Desktop/examples/antv/node_modules/inversify/src/utils/serialization.ts'"
So do you know how to resolve this? Thank you

Comment: For some reason this does not work in `React.StrictMode`. Remove `React.StrictMode` from index.js and it will work fine. .Sorry but I don't know how to remove these warning. but if we ignore these works. It works perfectly fine on browser. @JtaDD

Comment: it still not work :((( but many thank for you help <3

Comment: @JtaDD can you share your full code. It worked for me when I removed `React.StrictMode` from `index.js`.